# How to put PIL.Image.Image image QPushButton(PyQt)

Tags: python, pyqt

I get an image object like this:

```py
im = w.to_image()
print(type(im))
#<class 'PIL.Image.Image'>
```

How to put it in a `QPushButton`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you convert `PIL.image` to `QImage` by [ImageQt](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imageqt.htm).

`QPushButton()` can have `QIcon` as image.

`QIcon` requires `QPixmap`.

`QPixmap` can be made from `QImage`.

```
image = ImageQt(PIL.image)

pixmap = QPixmap(image)

icon = QIcon(pixmap)

pushbutton.setIcon(icon)
```

Comment: It works.Thank you!
ADD: 
(QPixmap made from QImage)
   pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(image)

Comment: Yes, but there is the case "class QtGui.QPixmap(image)", you can set the image in constructor.I wonder if this is changed ...?